# How to compute $\int_0^1\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\zeta(2)\right)\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-functions, polylogarithm

How to compute

> $$\int_0^1\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\zeta(2)\right)\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx$$

where $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}$ is the dilogarithm function.

---

I came across this integral while trying to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}H_n^2}{(2n+1)^2}$. If we apply integration by parts, one of the integral is manageable and the second one is $\int_0^1\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\zeta(2)\right)\frac{\tanh^{-1}x\ln(1-x^2)x}{1-x^2}\ dx$ which I could not finalize. So any idea how to solve any of these two integrals?

In case you are curious about the sum, Cornel provided the closed form [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2461107577319359&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the **Cornel**'s reduction of the $\operatorname{arctanh}$ integral to manageable integrals by using *clever* integrations by parts and exploiting ***Dilogarithm reflection formula*** in $(5)$ here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html.

$$I=\frac{1}{16} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2(x)}{x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{known}}-\frac{1}{16} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2(2-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{may use series with 
powers of 2 in denominator}}\\-\frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2(x)}{2-x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{may use series with 
powers of 2 in denominator}}-\frac{3}{8} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \log (x) \log (2-x)}{2-x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{may use series with 
powers of 2 in denominator}}\\+\frac{5}{64} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^4(1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{known}}-\frac{1}{12} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x) \log ^3(1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{known}}\\-\frac{7}{16} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-x) \log (x) \log (1+x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Calculated in (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series}}-\frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log^3(x)\log(1-x)}{2-x}\textrm{d}x}_{\text{may use series with 
powers of 2 in denominator}}\\-\frac{7}{32} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(1-x) \log ^2(1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{known}}.$$

Some of these integrals are already known. The harder ones can be easily reduced to advanced alternating harmonic series of weight $5$ or to advanced harmonic series of weight $5$ with powers of $2$ in denominator (and these ones are all already known). Also, playing with these integrals it's possible to get even more shortcuts. With this *form* of the main integral to calculate you're done.

**A NOTE:** The integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-x) \log (x) \log (1+x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x$ may be found calculated in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, pages $527$-$528$. In general, the integrals above where it is suggested a reduction to the series with powers of $2$ in denominator may also be rearranged and reduced to alternating harmonic series of weight $5$. End of story.